# Read from different folders using the value of the loop in makefile

Tags: linux, loops, makefile

am trying to read from different folders which their names are specified by the value of the loop, how can I do that. I have tried different ways but am normally getting an error.

like for the code given below, I would like to read from directory ss1,ss2,ss5,ss7 and ss10. this values are defined in the loop.(The folders already exist) (Am new to makefiles).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
all:
    for number in 1 2 5 7 10 ; do \
        echo $$number ; \
        echo "outstanding_misses="$$number >> collect.txt;  \
        awk 'NR==5' ./ss$$number/sim.out >> ./collect.txt;    \
        awk 'NR==23' ./ss$$number/sim.out >> ./collect.txt;    \
        awk 'NR==28' ./ss$$number/sim.out >> ./collect.txt;    \
    done
```

The error i get is as follows from the terminal:

```
awk: read error (Is a directory)
awk: read error (Is a directory)
awk: read error (Is a directory)
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Does removing the space after `ss$$number` help?

Comment: @choroba am trying to get values from different files which are stored in different folders, the folder names are defined  by the loop number i.e. if the loop has values 1,2,3. the folder names are as follows: ss1 ss2 and ss3. (the last character is equal to the loop number).
and removing the space doesn't help

Comment: You cannot read from a directory, you can only read from a file.

Comment: @choroba and there is no other way around it? as I can manually do it but i would like to use loops to make my task easier

Comment: I don't understand. A directory doesn't contain any data, it contains files. What do you want to read?

Comment: @choroba let say we have the file named sim.out in a directory named ss1,ss2 and ss3. and I am one level up in the directory i.e. my current directory==  ./   sim.out file is stored in ./ss1/sim.out , ./ss2/sim.out and ./ss3/sim.out. Now if I do it manually i can get it done and retrieve information from each of the files in the different directory but how would i do in a loop?

Comment: As @choroba mentioned in the very first comment, why do you have a space after the `$$number` variable?  By adding a space here you're breaking this into two arguments to `awk`, a directory followed by another path.  `awk` will try to read from the directory itself, not the file in the directory, which is not possible.  You should write: `awk 'NR==5' ./ss$$number/sim.out >> ./collect.txt;` (note no space after `$$number`).

Comment: Why '$$'  ? this will put the PID into the folder name.